# Setting up Chrome bookmark to customizeable URL

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I'd like to set up a Chrome bookmark that allows me to input a piece of the URL. For example, I have 3 pages on a website I visit - www.fakewebsite.com/1, www.fakewebsite.com/2, www.fakewebsite.com/3

Is it possible to set up a bookmark that will prompt me for a page addition? I'm picturing one of two options:

1) I click on the bookmark, it prompts me for an input, and when I type "3" it takes me to www.fakewebsite.com/3

2) There's an input box in the chrome bookmark bar (or URL space) where I can type in "3", hit enter, and it will take me to www.fakewebsite.com/3

EDIT: I've figured out a workaround. If I set up the website as a customizable search engine with a keyword, then I can do a quick search to get there, but I'd still be interested in knowing how either of the two above options could work (if possible). As a description of what I've done, I added a custom search engine with the following properties:

Name: fakewebsite
Keyword: FW
URL: http://www.fakewebsite.com/%s

Now when I go to the URL box and type "FW 3" it brings me to the above URL but with %s replaced with the search text.